# how to check if a parameter is present in the querystring in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to validate if a parameter is exits in the querystring or not in the node.js ?

I am validating like this

```
if(prm1 == null)
return error
```

But actually in the console.log(prm1)
says undefined..

How to validate this exactly ?

Comment: try if(prm), it exists, or if(!prm) it doesnot exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the parameter is not present in your queryString it is returned as `undefined`. The parameter wouldn't return `null` because it wasn't initialised.

try this :

```
if(typeof prm1 != 'undefined')
    return "error";
```

Comment: but undefined has to be validated like this
if(typeof prm1 != 'undefined')
    return "error";

or 

if(typeof prm1 != undefined)
    return "error";

Comment: the best way is if(typeof prm1 != 'undefined') because typeof return type in String. If you try test undefined type directly, use if(prm1 !== undefined) but it's slow

Comment: Hi , Suppose "/mobile/custom/******/deviceVersion/:deviceType" is my request . could you please tell me how to check "deviceType" against undefined or null?